# fedex-Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

[image]

I am putting the fedex credential and enable for checkout.

when click on proceed to checkout i got this error 
**sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.**

I put the shipping address

10853 Rose Ave,
Los Angeles,california,US

and after i click on Continue button i got this error .

Why this error is coming ? .. And also  i am able to shipping with other method that is **flat rate** . Please help me . and what is this error **"Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address.
"**

Comment: I am able to create the order using flat rate shipping method but not with fedex.

Comment: Can you double check that applying this patch fixes the issue? http://blog.philwinkle.com/the-fedex-api-changed-what-now/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi my problem is with server. server request is not connected to fedex .our company server is request restricted by admin person .you can check log /shipping_fedex file. if [result] => Array
        (
            [error] => looks like we got no XML document
            [code] => 0
        )
this indicate that your request is not reach to fedex .thank you all for support.

Comment: I figured out that the web services url was blocked in my office. I went home and carried out the process from different network and Voila ! It worked smoothly

Answer (score 3):

In order to fully diagnose this the logs need to be looked at. You can switch on logs via selecting debug in FedEx and then activating under the Developer logs. You will then see in var/log as a separate log file. If you have a WSA extension installed there is a built in admin logger present.

If you are using FedEx Box then it is going to restrict what is offered back, I'd suggest changing to 'Your Packaging' unless you have a definite need for that. FedEx Boxes are not transportable via Ground/Home Delivery, only priority services as I understand (so if you don't have these enabled in allowed methods it won't display rates).

We haven't seen any issues from our customers this week re FedEx, and given the amount of customers we have running shipping extensions we usually see very quickly.

Cameron, if you are getting a blank screen this implies a bug in the magento code. Check if you have installed anything on the site recently as may be impacting. Check the var/log/error.log as it will more than likely show the cause.

If still getting issues drop me a mail via the contact form on the WebShopApps site (I don't want to put my personal email on here).  I can diagnose these types of problems in <5 mins if you send ftp/admin and a cart login showing scenario. This is not an open invite to get millions of requests btw, we usually charge as we would be inundated but for Cameron and Ranjeet happy to take a quick look ;)

Comment: Packaging :fedex box, Dropoff:Regular pickup,Weight Unit:Pounds,Maximum Package Weight:150,Calculate Handling Fee:fixed,Handling Applied:Per package,Handling Fee:empty ,Residential Delivery:Yes,Allowed Methods:International delivery,Free Method:Home delivery this what i set up n magento fedex ..is there anything i made wrong in set up

Comment: karen,TBi infotech thanks... how to solve this problem even i change fedex box to Your Packaging and all other setting i kept same ..Please help

Comment: As I said you need to look at the logs.  It will tell you why its being refused in most cases.

Comment: Thanks karen .You are right .We can check log and find the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have inserted right details and also please fill complete address in checkout process including right zip code.

Check select mode for which you have details (live or sendbox).
Also you can follow this [LINK](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-fedex-shipping-in-magento/)

Comment: My credentials are production and sandbox mode :no  i am using right zipcode ..still coming this problem..are sure this problem comes only when there is address problems? thanks  for flat rate its working fine with my address that is used for fedex also ...so my address is correct otherwise it wont work for flat rate right?

Comment: I figured out that the web services url was blocked in my office. I went home and carried out the process from different network and Voila ! It worked smoothly

Answer (score 0):

**Follow same steps and its working fine.**

```
step 1 : Go to Admin Panel Locate Navigation System >> Configuration

Step 2 : Sales >> Shipping Methods >> Handling Fee text field put 0 value and save and Clear Cache and check fronted
```